# Spring integeration file markers for empty file

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I work with spring-integration FileSplitter and use FileMarker-s for ordered processing files, but for empty files i get IOException. Without FileMarker-s all works fine

stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at org.springframework.integration.file.splitter.FileSplitter$1.hasNext(FileSplitter.java:183)
... 50 more
```

xml-config:

```
<int:chain input-channel="channel.read.file" output-channel="channel.process.input">
    <int-file:splitter markers="true"/>
    <int:filter expression="!(payload instanceof T(org.springframework.integration.file.splitter.FileSplitter.FileMarker))"
            discard-channel="channel.process.file.marker"/>
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug to me - please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).